# C# custom events doesn't want to work with forms, partial class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I'm creating an app, there is some class that does some background operations and after all is done, parent object is notified using event. To provide event functionality i use following code:

```
public delegate void ShopStateChangedEventHandler(object sender, QuantityManagerEventArgs ea);

public event ShopStateChangedEventHandler ShopStateChanged;

protected virtual void WhenShopStateChanged(QuantityManagerEventArgs ea)
{
    if (ShopStateChanged != null)
    {
        ShopStateChanged(this, ea);
    }
}
```

It was working fine in all cases while I was using this piece of code with classes I've made, today I needed to have some custom made event added to one of forms in my application. Unfortunately i'm getting build error saying that compiler was unable to find **ShopStateChangedEventHandler** in form that is parent to form with custom event, and error is about line that adds listener

```
qmgr.ShopStateChanged += new ShopStateChangedEventHandler(qmgr_ShopStateChanged);
```

I really have no clue where to look for source of this error while in all other classes where i use this code all works fine, i suspect is it either because fact that the class i try to add custom event inherits from **Form** or maybe because it is **partial class**. As for now im far in the woods if it comes to solving it and I have no idea how to crunch it.

I hope you could suggest me what to do, or how to alter my code to make it all work with form.

thanks in advance 
mth

**EDIT**

error is **CS2046**
The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

all classes and forms belong to the same namespace

and as for **qmgr_ShopStateChanged** for now its just empty method

```
    void qmgr_ShopStateChanged(object sender, QuantityManagerEventArgs ea)
    {

    }
```

**qmgr** is instance of form that contains custom event code, **qmgr** and **qmgr_ShopStateChanged** along with code that creates listener and makes problem, belongs to main form of application (**frmMain**).

Comment: What error do yu get ? Can you also show qmgr_ShopStateChanged ?

Comment: where is this method ``qmgr_ShopStateChanged``??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your delegate directly on your namespace outside any class.